# How to undo the code which is written in R console

Tags: r

I am trying to undo the code written in the R console but I couldn't make it I need to go to the previous version of my data frame which is before I ran the code how can I do this

Comment: Once the variables are overwritten in memory, they are lost.  Unless a copy, or serialised version was created.

Answer (score 0):

I literally just did the same thing and lost two hours worth of webscrapping work :/

After you overwrite an object in R the previous version is gone forever.

A way to prevent this is to periodically create copies of your dataframe,.... especially before you do anything that you're not sure will work or result in the right answer. For example:

```
#don't do this:

kayak_df <- kayaks_df[is.na(kayaks_df$lat),]
```

**instead**:

```
#do this first:       (to save a copy)
kayaksdf2 <- kayaks_df



#then go ahead and run the questionable code
kayak_df <- kayaks_df[is.na(kayaks_df$lat),]
```

That way if you messed up your code you can go back and directly use `kayaks_df2` after you've fixed your code instead of having to re-create `kayaks_df` first . For example:

```
kayak_df2 <- kayaks_df2[!is.na(kayaks_df2$lat),]
```

Or you can run the sub-setting or transforming code without overwriting first to see what happens before you run code that overwrites the dataframe. For example:

```
# do this and see what happens first
kayaks_df[is.na(kayaks_df$lat),]

#instead of directly doing this
kayak_df <- kayaks_df[is.na(kayaks_df$lat),]
```